# Closing GUI (Python, tkinter, pyinstaller) gives - "Failed to Execute Script ...."

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

So my code and exe actually all seem to be work ok apart from one thing.
  When I try to close my GUI using the "X" on the top right I get the "Fatal Error" - "Failed to Execute Script ..script name.."

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqLhA.png)

If I use the script for what it is meant for, it runs fine and closes gracefully with no error messages.

Am I missing a simple line somewhere?
  I have attached the GUI code which uses tkinter below. Only the lines which I think might be relevant.

I have tried searching online, but the web is flooded with actual fail to run errors.

```
def UploadGUI():    

    folderPath = StringVar()
    var = IntVar()

    var.set(1)
    folderPath.set("D:\Data")

    btnFind = ttk.Button(gui, text="Browse Folder", command = lambda: folderPath.set(filedialog.askdirectory()))
    btnFind.place(x=340,y=77)


    d = ttk.Button(gui ,text="RUN", command = lambda: gui.destroy())
    d.place(x=190, y=150)

    gui.lift()
    gui.attributes('-topmost',True)
    gui.mainloop()
    return([folderPath.get(), var.get() ])
```

On clicking the "X" button, I'd expect the form to close normally without any errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error.

Comment: Hi Bryan, have attached a screenshot, thanks.